# Bag in index time bars. Pinescript

Tags: indexing, pine-script, hour

I have a trouble with the code. I did that an open buy order at 13 hour, but pinescript gives me open at 13 or 14 hour [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK2Oc.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgcoq.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxfy3.jpg). But it's not all... I'm doing open(current)<open(previous) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK2Oc.jpg) and the robot ignore this. What a hell?

```
if hour==HourBuy and TradeDateIsAllowed()==1 and open>Trend and open<open[1]
    enterlong:=1
 
if hour==HourSell and TradeDateIsAllowed()==1 and open<Trend 
    entershort:=1
```

Comment: `hour` gives you the hour in exchange time. If your chart is shown in a different timezone than "Exchange", it will lead to confusion. Put your chart in Exchange timezone, and you'll see that your script behaves correctly.

Comment: Wow, I got it! So much thanks, Yes, really works.